# Image only on first page header

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am pretty new to Word vba and I was helped with this code during the week. The code inserts an image into the header, my only challenge now is that I only want this image on the first page, however when I run the sub active, which should do this, nothing comes up on the original page. I am running the code through access database and everything is working okay, except this.

```
Public Sub UpdateHeader(oDoc As Word.Document)
        Dim oSec As Word.Section, rng As Range
        active oDoc
        For Each oSec In oDoc.Sections
            Set rng = oSec.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
                With rng
                    .Tables.Add Range:=rng, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
                    With .Tables(1)
                        .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                        .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=15, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
                        .Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\Images\Logo.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                    End With
                End With
        Next oSec

    End Sub

    Sub active(oDoc As Word.Document)

    oDoc.Sections.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Change  `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` to `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage`.

Comment: Thank you so much Kostas, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few details about headers in Word.

If you want to have a different header in the first page than the rest of the document, you can set it like this.

```
With oDoc.PageSetup
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
End With
```

Then you can add to the first page by getting the `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage` range, or `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` for all other pages.

Lastly, if you need to clear any existing headers and start fresh, you can do this:

```
Private Sub ClearExistingHeaders(oDoc As Word.Document)
    Dim oSec As Word.Section, oHeader As HeaderFooter
    For Each oSec In oDoc.Sections
        For Each oHeader In oSec.Headers
            oHeader.Range.Delete
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If this answer helped you; please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps others to find a working solution.